# Issue when replacing a crates dependency with a local version

Tags: rust

So I am trying to serialize a struct using bincode following these [instructions](https://peteris.rocks/blog/serialize-any-object-to-a-binary-format-in-rust/), and I was able to get that to work.

But then I wanted to serialize a struct with an `IpAddr` enum. Since `IpAddr` doesn't implement the `Encodable` trait needed, I downloaded the rustc_serialize crate from git and implemented encodable for `IpAddr` myself. I then changed my `Cargo.toml` file to:

```
[dependencies]
# rustc-serialize = "0.3"
byteorder = "0.3"
bincode = "0.4"

[dependencies.rustc-serialize]
path = "src/rustc-serialize-master"
```

But now, the same code from the struct I was using doesn't compile saying that 
`rustc_serialize::serialize::Encodable` is not implemented for my struct even though i have `#[derive(RustcEncodable)]` above the struct.

Even when I get rid of the code I added to the local version of rustc_serialize, I still get that error.

I think it might be due to something being screwed up with the way bincode and a local rustc_serialize interact, but I'm not sure.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's probably a bad idea to fork `rustc-serialize` to add an encoding for another type. It's likely more sane to implement the `Encodable` trait by hand for your struct that contains the `IpAddr`.

Comment: I tried that but I got an "only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types" error. It seems that you can't implement traits for traits you didn't define (imported rustc-serialize 'encodable` trait) for structs that you didn't define (imported IpAddr).

If you have been able to do that, please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: Check out [How do I implement a trait I don't own for a type I don't own?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25413201/155423). The wrapper type is the correct solution here. In your case, you already have a wrapper type (*serialize **a struct** with an IpAddr enum*). You can just manually implement `Encodable` for whatever your struct is.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So i've been trying to implement that, but I've been running into an error. So based on what the stack overflow you linked, I have
    ```impl Encodable for myStruct {
            fn encode .....  {
                    match *self {
                           IpAddr(_) => {},
                           _ => {},
}
}
}```

But I keep getting an `Unresolved enum variant, struct or const 'IpAddr'` error even though I've explicitly imported it using use, and I get the same error on built in types too. (P.S. How can you do code blocks in comments?) And thanks!

Comment: That's just some syntax that isn't needed in this case (I added a comment to the other question as well). You want something closer [to this](http://is.gd/2DwLtS). Also, you can't do code blocks in comments, as comments are supposed to be short and may be deleted.

Comment: Where you wrote the `// add appropriate error handling, pick the correct emit_* methods`, did you mean have a match statement for the `IpAddr` type and `String` type, in your example? Thanks

Comment: at this point, we are far off topic from your original question. I'd encourage you to ask a new one. That will allow future searchers to find it, instead of being buried in comments.

Comment: Ok. I will keep messing around with it first. If I still can't get it, I'll ask another question. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: To those that find this, I was able to implement the trait for the struct by following this site. http://valve.github.io/blog/2014/08/25/json-serialization-in-rust-part-1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please review the [Cargo documentation on overriding dependencies](http://doc.crates.io/specifying-dependencies.html#overriding-with-local-dependencies):

> To specify overrides, create a `.cargo/config` file in some ancestor of your project's directory (common places to put it is in the root of your code directory or in your home directory).
>
> Inside that file, put this:
>
> ```
> paths = ["/path/to/project/rand"]
> ```

Going deeper, you are likely running into [issue 22750](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22750) - two different versions of a crate interacting leads to unhelpful error messages. When you add rustc-serialize to your `dependencies`, you aren't *replacing* the old version, you are *adding* a new one.

In general, this is a good feature. If my project relies on crates A and B and they both rely on crate Z but with different versions, Rust can handle that just fine. The problem arises when they re-export items from those crates.

Comment: That alone seemed to have fixed it. Thanks!