# Can type associated constants be used to generalize array size arguments to functions?

Tags: types, rust

Rust's type system doesn't generalize over sizes, but with [type associated constants](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0195-associated-items.md) (new in Rust 1.20) I was thinking it may be possible to get some way towards this by declaring a constant size on a type.

Given functions that operate on fixed size arrays in Rust, is it possible/practical to use type constants to declare functions that take arbitrary array sizes or at least a pre-defined range of sizes (1..32) for example.

Take this small maths API for example:

```
// Cut down example of a math API

// Could be changed at compile time, otherwise quite limiting.
pub const DIMS: usize = 3;

pub fn sq(a: f64) -> f64 { a }

pub fn len_squared_vnvn(v0: &[f64; DIMS], v1: &[f64; DIMS]) -> f64 {
    let mut d = 0.0;
    for j in 0..DIMS {
        d += sq(v0[j] - v1[j]);
    }
    return d;
}

fn imul_vn_fl(v0: &mut [f64; DIMS], f: f64) {
    for j in 0..DIMS {
        v0[j] *= f;
    }
}
```

Could `DIMS` be moved to a type associated constant so that...

- Functions such as `imul_vn_fl` can be used with arbitrary fixed sized arrays.
- Support for passing primitive fixed size array types, eg: `[f64; SOME_CONSTANT_NUMBER]` or, more likely, a zero-cost conversion to a type that wraps a `[f64; #]` and defines the `DIMS` type constant.
- Use `std::convert::From`/`Into` to avoid having to explicitly write the casts whenever calling.
- Generated code should be exactly as efficient as if constant sizes were used (no runtime size checks).

I'm imagining something like this:

```
// this would be a macro to avoid re-writing for every size.
type f64v3 = u64;
impl VectorSize for f64v3 {
    const usize DIMS = 3;
}
// end macro

fn example() {
    let var: [f64; 3] = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0];
    imul_vn_fl(var, 0.5);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I don't have any details, but there's this: https://github.com/fizyk20/generic-array

Comment: Sorry, type-level constants are a highly-desired feature that aren't here yet: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1038

Comment: Rust 1.20 introduces type-associated constants, edited question to refer to type *associated* constants, instead of type-constants.

Comment: `type f64v3 = u64; impl VectorSize for f64v3 {}` — This would never be able to work [because type aliases do not create new types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35568871/155423). You'd immediately run into issues implementing the trait multiple times for the same type.

Answer (score 2):

The (current?) limitation of associated constants is that they can't be called on generic types.
I.e., following your example, with associated constants you can do this:

```
trait VectorSize {
    const DIMS: usize;
}

impl VectorSize for u64 {
    const DIMS: usize = 3usize;
}

fn imul_vn_fl(v0: &mut [f64; u64::DIMS], f: f64) {
    for j in 0..u64::DIMS {
        v0[j] *= f;
    }
}
```

but you would ultimately want to be able to make `imul_vn_fl` generic and  have it use the DIMS that is defined on your type. This is where associated constants still fall short (see the first of "shortcomings" in https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29646)

```
// this does not compile, unfortunately; T must be a concrete type
fn imul_vn_fl<T>(v0: &mut [f64; T::DIMS], f: f64) 
where
    T:VectorSize 
{
    for j in 0..T::DIMS {
        v0[j] *= f;
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=98babf1fcdfe2f6f431c72dc3dcafe29&version=stable)