# How do I implement Debug for a struct containing a function type alias?

Tags: rust

I have the following type:

```
type RangeFn = fn(&Value, &Value) -> bool;
```

Now I want to put it with this `struct`:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Range {
    fun: RangeFn,
}
```

But if I have a `struct` that takes `RangeFn` as a parameter, then I can't seem to have it derive from `Debug`. How do I make `RangeFn` compatible with the `Debug` trait?

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Is it possible to implement inherent methods on type aliases?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35568871/155423) and [How do I implement a trait I don't own for a type I don't own?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25413201/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: TL;DR: You don't, you can't, and that's by design.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to implement inherent methods on type aliases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35568871/is-it-possible-to-implement-inherent-methods-on-type-aliases)

Comment: @E_net4 I don't think he actually wants to implement `Debug` on the type alias, but to implement `Debug` on `Range`, which cannot simply derive it, as it is usually done.

Comment: Looks a bit like an XY problem to me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[You can't implement (or derive) a trait you don't own on a type you don't own.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25413201/155423)

However, that's not what you want to do. What you want is to implement `Debug` for `Range`, but you can't do that by deriving because `fn`s don't implement `Debug`.
Indeed, deriving `Debug` requires all fields to be `Debug` as well. Then you are stuck with implementing `Debug` by yourself; It is after all, just a normal trait:

```
type RangeFn = fn(&(), &()) -> bool;

struct Range {
    fun: RangeFn,
    other_field: u32,
}

impl std::fmt::Debug for Range {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::result::Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
        f.debug_struct("Range")
            .field("other_field", &self.other_field)
            .finish()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let r = Range {
        fun: |_, _| true,
        other_field: 42,
    };

    println!("{:?}", r);
}
```

([link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=07b1edd344ed321588aff7bef680458d&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

Comment: Ah thank you! Only thing is I wonder how to capture the signature of the function when printing it.

Comment: @MaxAlexander that's not possible in stable Rust. See [Expose the `type_name` intrinsic](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1428), and maybe drop your use case there, there has been recent activity.

Comment: Since my previous comment was posted, [`type_name`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/any/fn.type_name.html) has been stabilized.