Implement Debug for dyn Fn() member
I have a struct where one member is a dyn Fn().
#[derive(Debug)]
struct C {
    call: dyn Fn()
}

fn main() {
    
}

When I try to use #[derive(Debug)] on my struct, I get the following error:
3 |     call: dyn Fn()
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `(dyn Fn() + 'static)` cannot be formatted using `{:?}` because it doesn't implement `Debug`

I tried implementing Debug as follows:
#[derive(Debug)]
struct C {
    call: dyn Fn()
}

impl std::fmt::Debug for dyn Fn() {
    
}

fn main() {
    
}

However, I get:
6 | impl std::fmt::Debug for dyn Fn() {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--------
  | |                        |
  | |                        `dyn Fn()` is not defined in the current crate
  | impl doesn't use only types from inside the current crate
  |
  = note: define and implement a trait or new type instead

What exactly does Rust want me to do and what is the typical solution to the problem?
Does it say that I should wrap my dyn Fn in an extra struct which I implement Debug for?

You can only implement traits if your crate defines the trait or the type you are implementing it for yourself. That's your second error, it will not work. As for implementing Debug on C, how would you like call to be formatted as a string?

Perhaps you could format the function as a pointer to the function's location? Though you would need to implement it on C as you can't extend dyn Fn

Almost duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52029790/how-do-i-implement-debug-for-a-struct-containing-a-function-type-alias

@TanveerBadar I would just like it to print Fn or nothing. The real struct has 5 other members that I'm actually interested in printing.

You can't impl std::fmt::Debug for dyn Fn() because neither the trait Debug nor the type dyn Fn() is local. You can use a wrapper but that means you now have to use the wrapper in C and the wrapper isn't able to add any information either, so the core problem remains.
Most likely you just want to implement Debug for C yourself:
struct C {
    other_field: &'static str, // for demonstration
    call: dyn Fn(),
}

impl std::fmt::Debug for C {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        f
            .debug_struct("C")
            .field("other_field", &self.other_field)
            .finish_non_exhaustive()
    }
}

But there isn't any meaningful output we can get for a dyn Fn() so I've omitted it in the code above and used finish_non_exhaustive to indicate omitted fields.

As explained by @cafce25, the reason you can't do this is that you can only implement a trait for a type if at least one of them is local to your crate. The rationale behind this restriction is known as implementation coherence.
To explain it with less technical jargon, here's an example from The Rust Book:

But we can’t implement external traits on external types. For example, we can’t implement the Display trait on Vec<T> within our aggregator crate, because Display and Vec<T> are both defined in the standard library and aren’t local to our aggregator crate. This restriction is part of a property called coherence, and more specifically the orphan rule, so named because the parent type is not present. This rule ensures that other people’s code can’t break your code and vice versa. Without the rule, two crates could implement the same trait for the same type, and Rust wouldn’t know which implementation to use.


The way around it is to write an impl block that doesn't rely on call having a Debug implementation. @cafce25 showed how you can write such an impl manually, but I would actually suggest using the derivative crate, which allows you to customise the derived Debug implementation.
Here's an example. I have wrapped your dyn Fn() in a Box so C is Sized and therefore can be constructed on the stack, but it doesn't affect what I'm trying to demonstrate:
#[derive(derivative::Derivative)]
#[derivative(Debug)]
struct C {
    #[derivative(Debug(format_with = "fmt_fn"))]
    call: Box<dyn Fn()>,
}
fn fmt_fn(_: &dyn Fn(), f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
    write!(f, "Opaque Fn")
}

fn main() {
    fn foo() {}
    let c = C { call: Box::new(foo) };
    println!("{c:?}");
}

See derivative documentation for all customisation options.
