# Is it possible to #[derive] traits on crate-included structs?

Tags: struct, rust, traits

If I have something like

```
use serde_json;
use iso8601::DateTime;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Thing {
    pub attr: i32,
    pub foo: i32,
    pub ts: DateTime
}
```

The compiler is also going to insist that I ensure `DateTime` satisfies the trait bound `Deserialize`:

```
error: the trait bound `iso8601::DateTime: serde::Deserialize` is not satisfied [E0277]
src/lib.rs:208   #[derive(Deserialize, Debug)
```

You can't place the derive annotation above the included struct, or the compiler will complain. In fact, the plot thickens, as `DateTime` itself has [structs](http://badboy.github.io/iso8601/iso8601/struct.DateTime.html) that would need the same annotation:

```
pub struct DateTime {
    pub date: Date,
    pub time: Time,
}
```

Is there a way to swing this, or do I have to implement these traits manually for external structs?

Edit: Let me be clear, I was asking about the `#[derive]` macro. I read the linked and related questions, and I understand that I can provide my own implementation of different traits, as well as use newtypes etc. That is not what I am asking about.

#### Cargo.toml

```
serde = "0.8"
serde_json = "0.8"
serde_macros = "0.8"
iso8601 = "0.1.1"
```

Comment: A simple "no" answer with relevant information would be more useful (in the SO sense) than voting to close as duplicate. Edited to explain further.

Comment: The relevant information *is* the linked duplicate and [the question it is a duplicate of](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25413201/155423). *How* you attempt to implement the trait is immaterial, it still cannot be done.

Comment: I don't mean any offense by it, but I disagree that the 'how' is immaterial--it's not immaterial to me. I would like to know whether or not the code intended to be generated by a custom `derive` macro can be applied to an imported struct, especially one that wraps other imported structs. In this same vein, the question you link to mentions the [newtype_derive](https://crates.io/crates/newtype_derive) crate, which might provide a macro for this job. So which is it? Not possible, or not expressible this way? Because the linked question puts both of those forks in question without answering them.

Comment: In my opinion, this is one of the most important reasons to implement a fix for this issue. Aside from suffering from strange "wrapping" issues with the new type, implementing this manually can be a large amount of code duplication, depending on the trait being implemented and the level of nesting.