# How can I use a cgmath::Matrix as a uniform parameter in glium?

Tags: rust, glium

I'm trying to integrate the `cgmath` library into my first experiments with `glium`, but I can't figure out how to pass my `Matrix4` object to the `draw()` call.

My `uniforms` object is defined thus:

```
let uniforms = uniform! {
    matrix: cgmath::Matrix4::from_scale(0.1)
};
```

and this is my `draw` call:

```
target.draw(&vertex_buffer, &index_slice, &program, &uniforms, &Default::default())
      .unwrap();
```

which fails to compile with the message

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `cgmath::Matrix4<{float}>: glium::uniforms::AsUniformValue` is not satisfied
```

I'm a total beginner with Rust, but I do believe I cannot implement this trait myself, as both it and the `Matrix4` type are in a crate separate from mine.

Is there really no better option than to manually convert the matrix into an array of arrays of floats?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I implement a trait I don't own for a type I don't own](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25413201/155423)?

Comment: @shepmaster: it's not really a duplicate, because I don't really want to implement that trait unless there's no better way. The link is informative though - thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I do believe I cannot implement this trait myself, as both it and the `Matrix4` type are in a crate separate from mine.

This is very true.

> Is there really no better option than to manually convert the matrix into an array of arrays of floats?

Well, you don't have to do a lot manually.

First, it's useful to note that `Matrix4<S>` [implements `Into<[[S; 4]; 4]>`](http://brendanzab.github.io/cgmath/cgmath/struct.Matrix4.html) (I can't link to that impl directly, so you have to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>). That means that you can easily convert a `Matrix4` into an array which is accepted by glium. Unfortunately, `into()` only works when the compiler knows exactly what type to convert to. So here is a non-working and a working version:

```
// Not working, the macro accepts many types, so the compiler can't be sure 
let uniforms = uniform! {
    matrix: cgmath::Matrix4::from_scale(0.1).into()
};

// Works, because we excplicitly mention the type
let matrix: [[f64; 4]; 4] = cgmath::Matrix::from_scale(0.1).into();
let uniforms = uniform! {
    matrix: matrix,  
};
```

---

But this solution might be still too much to write. When I worked with `cgmath` and `glium`, I created a helper trait to reduce code size even more. This might not be the best solution, but it works and has no obvious downsides (AFAIK).

```
pub trait ToArr {
    type Output;
    fn to_arr(&self) -> Self::Output;
}

impl<T: BaseNum> ToArr for Matrix4<T> {
    type Output = [[T; 4]; 4];
    fn to_arr(&self) -> Self::Output {
        (*self).into()
    }
}
```

I hope this code explains itself. With this trait, you now only have to `use` the trait near the `draw()` call and then:

```
let uniforms = uniform! {
    matrix: cgmath::Matrix4::from_scale(0.1).to_arr(),
    //                                      ^^^^^^^^^
};
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas, that did the trick! I'm so new to Rust (started on Monday 3 days ago) that it didn't occur to me that there was nothing stopping me from defining and implementing my *own* trait. (Even so, I couldn't have come up with this on my own, too much left to learn still.) Out of curiosity, why did you stop doing stuff with cgmath and glium?

Comment: sorry @LukasKalbertodt forgot to correctly include your name in the above comment.

Comment: @JPNotADragon The name is not a problem, when you are commenting on my answer, since I get notified anyway ;-) Glad I could help. I did not stop working with `cgmath` or `glium`; sorry if my answer seem to imply it. I really like `cgmath` and think its design is terrific. While generally being pretty nice to use, `glium` has some design flaws, which tomaka itself acknowledges. A rewrite [is being considered](https://github.com/tomaka/glium2). But `glium` is still OK, so don't stop using it ;-)

Comment: Thanks! That's the answer I was hoping for :-)