# Unconstrained type parameter implementing IntoIterator

Tags: generics, rust, associated-types, generic-associated-types

How do I implement IntoIterator with a generic type parameter without getting into this kind of error, I think is the same error than [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43933348/unconstrained-type-parameter-error) but the solution proposed there is not valid in this context, also doing a method called `iter` on `Counter` would solve the issue but it won't be idiomatic

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)]
pub struct Id(u32);

struct Counter {
    top: u32
}

struct Iter<R: Iterator<Item = Id>>(R);  

impl<R> Iterator for Iter<R>
where
    R: Iterator<Item = Id> 
{
    type Item = Id;
    
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.0.next()
    }
}

// Unconstrained type parameter `I`
impl<I> IntoIterator for Counter 
where
    I: Iterator<Item = Id>
{
    type Item = Id;
    type IntoIter = I;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        Iter(0..self.top)
    }
}
```

This is the behaviour I expect from the implementation.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut counter = Counter { top: 3 };
    assert_eq!(
        counter.into_iter().collect::<Vec<Id>>(),
        vec![Id(0), Id(1), Id(2)]
    );
}
```

[Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0cfa2296edb24f1657d1a8205cdbcaf9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved without needing the `I` type parameter:

```rust
struct Iter<R: Iterator<Item = u32>>(R);

impl<R> Iterator for Iter<R>
where
    R: Iterator<Item = u32>,
{
    type Item = Id;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.0.next().map(Id)
    }
}

impl IntoIterator for Counter {
    type Item = Id;
    type IntoIter = Iter<std::ops::Range<u32>>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        Iter(0..self.top)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=700f2a30105c2185c357d00ab33d5dc2)