# Reading data from file into a GenericArray

Tags: arrays, generics, rust, traits

I am using the [generic_array crate](https://github.com/fizyk20/generic-array) in Rust.  I want fixed length arrays, so `Vec` is not appropriate, but I want the length of the array to be defined at runtime, hence using this crate instead of `array`.

The code is for a clustering algorithm, where each generic array represents a data point.  I want the data to be of any dimension.  For example, if I was clustering pixels on an image, I might have 3D data, one for each colour channel; but I don't want the code to only be able to be used on 3D data.

I'm having issues with reading data from a CSV file into a generic array.  Before using generic arrays, I had a 2D struct that derived from `RustcDecodable`.

How best to implement reading data from a file into a `GenericArray`? I can't implement the `Decodable` trait for `GenericArray`, [as the `Decodable` trait is external](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0117).

Here is what my code looked like when I was only allowing 2D data:

```
use std::path::Path;

extern crate csv;
extern crate rustc_serialize;

/// Store one data point's (or one cluster centroid's) x and y co-ordinates
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, RustcDecodable)]
pub struct DataPoint {
    pub x: f64,
    pub y: f64,
}

impl DataPoint {

    pub fn squared_euclidean_distance(&self, other: &DataPoint) -> f64 {
        (other.x - self.x).powi(2) + (other.y - self.y).powi(2)
    }
}

pub fn read_data<P>(file_path: P) -> Vec<DataPoint>
    where P: AsRef<Path>
{
    let mut reader = csv::Reader::from_file(file_path).unwrap();
    reader.decode().map(|point| point.unwrap()).collect()
}
```

Here is what my code looks like with `GenericArray`s (minus `read_data` function):

```
extern crate generic_array;

trait Euclidean<N> {
    fn squared_euclidean_distance(&self, other: &generic_array::GenericArray<f64, N>) -> f64
        where N: generic_array::ArrayLength<f64>;
}


impl <N> Euclidean<N> for generic_array::GenericArray<f64, N>
    where N: generic_array::ArrayLength<f64>
{
    fn squared_euclidean_distance(&self, other: &generic_array::GenericArray<f64, N>) -> f64
        where N: generic_array::ArrayLength<f64>
    {
        let iter = self.iter().zip(other.iter());
        iter.fold(0.0, |acc, x| acc + (x.0 - x.1).powi(2))
    }
}
```

Should I read the data into something intermediate, then into the `GenericArray`?  Should I define my own version of the `Decodable` trait?  Should I give up on generic arrays?

Comment: Why is using `Vec` not appropriate? Just because it *can* change size does not mean it *has* to.

Comment: You could use a NewType like explained here: http://valve.github.io/blog/2014/08/26/json-serialization-in-rust-part-2/

Comment: @MatthieuM. I want a data structure that can't change size -- using one that _could_ leaves room for bugs and doesn't feel like a nice choice of data structure.  I'd rather use a type that guarantees the behaviour I want.

Comment: @Neikos do you mean creating a tuple struct containing the generic array, and deriving `RustcDecodable` on that?  I had previously tried this (sorry for not including in post), and get the following error:  `error[E0277]: the trait bound \`generic_array::GenericArray<f64, _>: rustc_serialize::Decodable\` is not satisfied`

Comment: A `Vec`-like structure with a fixed size? How about a `Box<[T]>`?

Comment: @lochsh Yes, it would contain it, but then you can implement the Decodable trait manually check the "Deserializing fixed length arrays" part in the post I linked

Comment: @Neikos thanks!  I will look tomorrow more closely (busy atm), it sounds very promising :)

Comment: If you use a newtype, please mark this question a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/25413201/155423.

Comment: Newtype did indeed solve my problem.  Thank you very much @Neikos.  I will mark as duplicate :)