# Impl Add for type alias tuple (f64, f64)

Tags: types, rust

I have a custom type Point

```
type Point = (f64, f64);
```

And I want to add two `Point`s together but I get this error

```
error[E0368]: binary assignment operation `+=` cannot be applied to type `(f64, f64)`
   --> src/main.rs:119:21
    |
119 |                     force_map[&body.name] += force;
    |                     ---------------------^^^^^^^^^
    |                     |
    |                     cannot use `+=` on type `(f64, f64)`
```

And when I try implementing Add, I get this error:

```
39 | / impl Add for (f64, f64) {
40 | |     #[inline(always)]
41 | |     fn add(self, other: (f64, f64)) -> (f64, f64)  {
42 | |         // Probably it will be optimized to not actually copy self and rhs for each call !
43 | |         (self.0 + other.0, self.1 + other.1);
44 | |     }
45 | | }
   | |_^ impl doesn't use types inside crate
   |
   = note: the impl does not reference any types defined in this crate
   = note: define and implement a trait or new type instead
```

Is it possible to implement `Add` for a `type`? Should I use a `struct` instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I implement a trait I don't own for a type I don't own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413201/how-do-i-implement-a-trait-i-dont-own-for-a-type-i-dont-own)

Comment: Type aliases aren't new types, they're just shorthand for existing ones. [Advanced Types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-04-advanced-types.html) (title is slightly misleading)

Comment: Ok thanks, is it possible to impl Add on a type (f64, f64)?

Comment: You don't control the `Add` trait, and you don't control the type `(f64, f64)`, so no, the coherence rules forbid it.

Comment: If you add that answer I can close the question, thank you

Comment: The answer is essentially "you can't implement a trait you don't own  for a type you don't own", which is what the linked duplicate says. What clarification do you believe is necessary?

Comment: I meant add it as an answer to the question so I can accept it as correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you don't have a `Point` type. The `type` keyword unfortunately does not create a new type, but only a new name (alias) for an existing type.

To create a type, use:

```
struct Point(f64, f64);
```