# Why do I get an error "cannot define inherent `impl` for a type outside of the crate where the type is defined" when writing an impl for a type alias?

Tags: rust

I hope to implement the function for type `OpResource`.

```
type OpResource = Object<OC, Status>;

impl OpResource {
    pub fn get_parameter_values(&self) -> Vec<ParameterValue> {
        self.spec
            .parameter_values
            .clone()
            .or_else(|| Some(vec![]))
            .unwrap()
    }
}
```

Then I got an error

```
error[E0116]: cannot define inherent `impl` for a type outside of the crate where the type is defined
   |
35 | / impl OpResource {
36 | |     pub fn get_parameter_values(&self) -> Vec<ParameterValue> {
37 | |         self.spec
38 | |             .parameter_values
...  |
42 | |     }
43 | | }
   | |_^ impl for type defined outside of crate.
   |
   = note: define and implement a trait or new type instead
```

I can't understand where am I wrong, I just implement the function below the type, why it said I'm out of crate?

Comment: Hi there! I think your question is answered by [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47992959/impl-add-for-type-alias-tuple-f64-f64). Summary: a `type` alias does not create a new type; it's just an alias. That means writing an `impl` is like writing an impl for the aliased type and is subject to [orphan rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413201/how-do-i-implement-a-trait-i-dont-own-for-a-type-i-dont-own). Please let us know if this answers your question!

Comment: You can't add an implementation for Object. You should define a trait and define a trait implementation. It's not much more work, you mainly have to add the method declarations.

Comment: thanks! @Lukas Kalbertodt

Comment: The duplicates refer to trait-impls, whereas this question is about inherent-impls and does not involve traits at all. However, I found a Reddit comment that explained why inherent impls on foreign types are undesirable as well: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/7agy4b/comment/dp9vvws/