# How to overload an operator for a generic right-hand operand?

Tags: generics, rust, operator-overloading, traits

I have a generic type, `Vec2<T>`, for which I would like to implement the following operation:

`Vec2<T> = T * Vec2<T>`

I have tried this:

```
impl<T: Copy + Mul<Output = T>> Mul<Vec2<T>> for T {
    type Output = Vec2<T>;

    fn mul(self, rhs: Vec2<T>) -> Vec2<T> {
        Vec2 {
            x: self * rhs.x,
            y: self * rhs.y,
        }
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

> type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local
>   type (e.g. `MyStruct<T>`); only traits defined in the current crate
>   can be implemented for a type parameter

What is the standard way to overload an operator with your own type as the right-hand operand?

[EDIT]

Apparently the answer is that you can't currently do this. There are some answers to related questions in the "duplicates". I await an update to the language so that this question can be reopened, and an actual answer can be given.

Comment: Note that you can implement `impl<T: Copy + Mul<Output = T>> Mul<T> for Vec2<T>` as a workaround.

Comment: @Boiethios Yep, I've already implemented that. Just can't figure out how to do it the other way around.

Comment: I think that this is not possible. Look at what they did [at cgmath](https://docs.rs/cgmath/0.16.0/cgmath/struct.Vector2.html). They implemented it in one way only (as you did). I find this interdiction strange since you can do that for every type you do not own: `impl Mul<Vec2<f32>> for f32` works.

Comment: I don't think that is currently possible, as the orphan rule in [RFC1023](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1023-rebalancing-coherence.md) forbids it. It would be nice of there were some workaround, for example Python has `__rmul__` for this purpose.

Comment: By saying `for T`, you are attempting to [implement a trait you don't own for a type you don't own](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25413201/155423). If **another** crate uses your `Vec2` **and** implements `Mul` for its own type, you'd have massive conflicts. This is not allowed.

Comment: See also [How do I overload an operator for all types that implement my trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45507028/155423).

Comment: @Shepmaster I wasn't asking why I get that error message. I was asking how to overload an operator where the right-hand operand is of my type. I included the example to show that I had already tried to solve my problem before asking. If it isn't currently possible, then there should be a direct answer to my question stating as much. This is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Ok, then I've updated the first duplicate to [How do I implement a trait I don't own (`Mul`) for a type I don't own (`T`)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25413201/155423). On Stack Overflow, the focus is not on that the *questions* are duplicates, it's on that the answers are duplicates.