# Why is implementing an external trait using my type as a parameter for an external type legal?

Tags: rust, traits, orphan

I am modifying some code to depend on rand version 0.5. At first, I was worried how I would enable generating random values of my own types with `Standard`, but I found out this is legal:

```
impl ::rand::distributions::Distribution<MyType> for ::rand::distributions::Standard {
    // ...
}
```

Why is it legal? I thought implementing an external trait for an external type is [illegal](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-02-traits.html#implementing-a-trait-on-a-type).

Comment: I think the rule is just simplified for the book. The compiler can allow more cases, like this one, if it's able to make sure that there can't be any conflicting implementations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The entire purpose of these rules (called the *orphan rules* or *coherence rules*) is to avoid having any conflicting implementations for a given trait/type combination. Since Rust 1.0, it is believed that it would not be in line with a language striving for solid stability to be "willy-nilly" about who is allowed to implement a trait for a type.

A very common example of this particular type of implementation is `From`:

```
impl From<MyType> for i32 {
    // ...
}
```

By parameterizing the trait with a local type, there's still no ambiguity about who is implementing the trait. One way of thinking about it would be treating `Distribution` as not a trait but a *trait constructor* <sup>1</sup>. Each instance of `Distribution` creates a new trait, one that's custom-made for the case.

See also:

- [RFC 2451, "Re-Rebalancing Coherence"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2451)
- [RFC 1023, "Rebalancing Coherence"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1023-rebalancing-coherence.md)
- [How do I implement a trait I don't own for a type I don't own?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25413201/155423)

<sup>1</sup> — This isn't true, but it's a reasonable analogy.