# How do I hash a struct using a type that implements the Digest trait from the sha2 crate, such as Sha256?

Tags: hash, rust

I'm trying to `Sha256` hash a struct to generate a GUID for that struct based on its contents.

```rust
use sha2::{Digest, Sha256};
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

#[derive(Hash)]
struct Person {
  firstName: String;
  lastName: String;
}

let a = Person {
   firstName: "bob".to_string(),
   lastName: "the builder".to_string()
}

let mut s = Sha256::new();
a.hash(&mut s);
println!("{}", s.finsih());
```

My stretch goal would be to simply use `a.id()` which would hash all the properties on that struct. Is this a `impl Person { id() -> String }`?

I tried using `impl x for y` but that threw a `impl doesn't use types inside crate`

```
impl Hasher for Sha256 {
    fn finish(&self) -> u64 {
        self.0.result()
    }

    fn write(&mut self, msg: &[u8]) {
        self.0.input(msg)
    }
}
```

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, fields and modules; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants. Use `first_name` and `last_name` instead, please.

Comment: The code you have provided isn't valid Rust syntax and contains typos, which demonstrates that you haven't even attempted to run the code.

Answer (score 9):

[You can't implement an external trait for an external type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25413201/155423).

Your issue is that the `digest` types, like `Sha256`, don't implement `Hasher` - because they're different kinds of hashes. The `Hasher` trait is for types which hash data [into a 64 bit hash value](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/trait.Hasher.html#tymethod.finish), for use in Rust's own code, like `HashMap`. `Sha256`, on the other hand, gives a hash of **32 bytes**.

To use `Sha256`, you need to manually feed it the bytes you want to compute the hash of - you can do this in an `impl` block.

```rust
impl Person {
    fn id(&self) -> sha2::digest::generic_array::GenericArray<u8, <Sha256 as Digest>::OutputSize> {
        let mut s = Sha256::new();
        s.input(self.firstName.as_bytes());
        s.input(self.lastName.as_bytes());
        s.result()
    }
}
```