# How can I implement the Deserialize trait on the BigInt struct from the num library?

Tags: data-structures, struct, rust, serde

I'm using [toml](https://docs.rs/toml/0.5.6/toml/) to parse data, and I have this struct:

```rust
use serde_derive::Deserialize;
use toml::value::Datetime;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct Trade {
    pub action: Action,
    pub date_time: Datetime,
    pub exchange: Exchange,
    pub fee: i64,
    pub id: Option<String>,
    pub matched: Option<bool>,
    pub price: i64,
    pub quantity: i64,
}
```

I'd like to replace the integers (`i64`) with [`BigInt`](https://docs.rs/num/0.2.1/num/bigint/struct.BigInt.html), a struct from the [num](https://docs.rs/num/0.2.1/num/) library.

Is this possible? Do I have to implement the `Deserialize` trait myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you cannot. See [How do I implement a trait I don't own for a type I don't own?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25413201/155423) for more details

For your specific case, `num` already has a [feature](https://github.com/rust-num/num#features) for that:

> The serde feature enables serialization for types in `num-bigint`, `num-complex`, and `num-rational`.

so just use it:

```
[dependencies.num]
version = "0.3"
features = ["serde"]
```