# Writing to disk parameters of Bellman in rust

Tags: rust

So i just started using rust, and started using the bellman crate.
I used the MimC example that was added to the bellman git account, and it seems like its calculating the parameters for the circuit each time you run the example. I want to use the example as a base for my code, and it seems redundant to calculate it each time for the same circuit so I waned to try and write params to the disk, and to check each time whether it exists or not for a specific circuit (so if it was already calculated, it will read it instead of calculating it).
Assuming params is a structure, I tried using serde and serde_json. but I keep on getting the following error:
^^^^^^^ the trait `serde::ser::Serialize` is not implemented for `bellman::groth16::Parameters<pairing::bls12_381::Bls12>`

any thoughts about how can I write it and read it later efficently?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

serde has a `Serialize`/`Deserialize` traits which should be derived/implemented in the crate where the types are defined. So usually it's a good idea to look at Cargo.toml (or documentation) for serde features, it's a pretty common practice to have it (and sometimes you need manually enable them). For the `bellman` crate however that doesn't seem to be implemented, so you need to workaround for "external" type ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413201/how-do-i-implement-a-trait-i-dont-own-for-a-type-i-dont-own?noredirect=1&lq=1)). Serde particularly has a fairly good support of that, take a look [at their doc](https://serde.rs/remote-derive.html). Simply, you need to provide a newtype to `#[serde(with = "<here-your-newtype>")]`, which mimics the original one.

Comment: This was the reason why I stopped using Rust the last time (I often stop using Rust...). I cannot really understand why implementing traits in a downstream package for types in an upstream package is not allowed.

Comment: That may lead to the conflicts. Assume crate A, which depends on B & C. Both B & C define a different implementation of some trait. Which implementation should be used in A then?

Comment: The usual approach (the approach I used to take in other similar situations) is to create a package D' which implements the missing features of D and then both B and C merrily use D'. But it appears, Rust prevents/hinders creating the D' for the same reason it would prevent both B and C from helping themselves to the missing features.