# How can I implement serde::Deserialize for arrays larger than 32?

Tags: arrays, rust, serde

I need to use 33-byte arrays. It looks like arrays up to and including 32 elements serialise without problems, but 33-byte arrays cause:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[u8; 33]: _::_serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:54:2
   |
54 |     foo: [u8; 33]
   |     ^^^ the trait `_::_serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `[u8; 33]`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <&'a [u8] as _::_serde::Deserialize<'de>>
             <[T; 0] as _::_serde::Deserialize<'de>>
             <[T; 10] as _::_serde::Deserialize<'de>>
             <[T; 11] as _::_serde::Deserialize<'de>>
           and 30 others
   = note: required by `_::_serde::de::MapAccess::next_value`
```

They evidently decided that 32 was a good place to stop. How can I add support for 33 element arrays?

Comment: A simple solution would be to use the [serde-big-array](https://crates.io/crates/serde-big-array) crate.

Comment: @L.Riemer Thanks, but serde-big-array does not support 33 elements, only 40, 48, 50, ... I'll see if I can cut and paste its lib.rs into my project in some way.

Comment: My bad. Yes, you just need to add a 33 to the big_array! macro call, might just do that using mcartons solution. It's basically the same code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't [implement a trait you don't own for a type you don't own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413201/how-do-i-implement-a-trait-i-dont-own-for-a-type-i-dont-own), but unfortunately, in this particular case, you don't have to.

---

For serialization, support of big arrays is pretty easy

> ```rust
> struct S {
>    #[serde(serialize_with = "<[_]>::serialize")]
>    arr: [u8; 256],
> }
> ```

[Source](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/631#issuecomment-279271870)

This coerces the array to a slice and serializes that instead.

---

For de-serialization, it is a bit more complicated.

serde's own author recommends the following

> ```rust
> #[macro_use] extern crate serde_derive;
>
> extern crate serde; extern crate serde_json;
>
> use std::fmt; use std::marker::PhantomData;
> use serde::ser::{Serialize, Serializer, SerializeTuple};
> use serde::de::{Deserialize, Deserializer, Visitor, SeqAccess, Error};
>
> trait BigArray<'de>: Sized {
>     fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
>         where S: Serializer;
>     fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
>         where D: Deserializer<'de>;
> }
>
> macro_rules! big_array {
>     ($($len:expr,)+) => {
>         $(
>             impl<'de, T> BigArray<'de> for [T; $len]
>                 where T: Default + Copy + Serialize + Deserialize<'de>
>             {
>                 fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
>                     where S: Serializer
>                 {
>                     let mut seq = serializer.serialize_tuple(self.len())?;
>                     for elem in &self[..] {
>                         seq.serialize_element(elem)?;
>                     }
>                     seq.end()
>                 }
>
>                 fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<[T; $len], D::Error>
>                     where D: Deserializer<'de>
>                 {
>                     struct ArrayVisitor<T> {
>                         element: PhantomData<T>,
>                     }
>
>                     impl<'de, T> Visitor<'de> for ArrayVisitor<T>
>                         where T: Default + Copy + Deserialize<'de>
>                     {
>                         type Value = [T; $len];
>
>                         fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
>                             formatter.write_str(concat!("an array of length ", $len))
>                         }
>
>                         fn visit_seq<A>(self, mut seq: A) -> Result<[T; $len], A::Error>
>                             where A: SeqAccess<'de>
>                         {
>                             let mut arr = [T::default(); $len];
>                             for i in 0..$len {
>                                 arr[i] = seq.next_element()?
>                                     .ok_or_else(|| Error::invalid_length(i, &self))?;
>                             }
>                             Ok(arr)
>                         }
>                     }
>
>                     let visitor = ArrayVisitor { element: PhantomData };
>                     deserializer.deserialize_tuple($len, visitor)
>                 }
>             }
>         )+
>     }
> }
>
> big_array! {
>     40, 48, 50, 56, 64, 72, 96, 100, 128, 160, 192, 200, 224, 256, 384, 512,
>     768, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, 65536, }
>
> #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
> struct S {
>     #[serde(with = "BigArray")]
>     arr: [u8; 64], }
>
> fn main() {
>     let s = S { arr: [1; 64] };
>     let j = serde_json::to_string(&s).unwrap();
>     println!("{}", j);
>     serde_json::from_str::<S>(&j).unwrap(); }
> ```

[Source](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/631#issuecomment-322677033)

This has been published in the [`serde-big-array`](https://crates.io/crates/serde-big-array) crate.