# How to generate implementation of my trait for foreign type?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I have a trait `HelloMacro`

```
pub trait HelloMacro {
    fn hello_macro();
}
```

And I've already implemented proc macro crate for this trait.

This is a usage, just like in the [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html?search=#how-to-write-a-custom-derive-macro):

```
use hello_macro::HelloMacro;
use hello_macro_derive::HelloMacro;

#[derive(HelloMacro)]
struct Pancakes;

fn main() {
    Pancakes::hello_macro();
}
```

But how I can use this `derive` with foreign type?

```
use some_lib::SomeType;
use hello_macro::HelloMacro;
use hello_macro_derive::HelloMacro;

// How to autoimplement HelloMacro for SomeType?

fn main() {
    SomeType::hello_macro();
}
```

Comment: I don't want to flag this as a direct duplicate of this question, but I suspect your question can be answered by this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413201/how-do-i-implement-a-trait-i-dont-own-for-a-type-i-dont-own

I believe the solution would be to create a wrapper struct (which contains the foreign type) and derive your trait on the wrapper. I hope this helps.

Comment: There's a [section on derive macros in the Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html#derive-macros). It's somewhat terse, but it may get you started.