# How can I implement serde for a type that I don't own and have it support compound /wrapper/collection types

Tags: rust, traits, serde

This question is similar
[How do I implement a trait I don't own for a type I don't own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413201/how-do-i-implement-a-trait-i-dont-own-for-a-type-i-dont-own)

I wrote a serializer for Date, using the mechanism described in the documentation with my module wrapping a serialize function

```
pub mod my_date_format {
    use chrono::{Date, NaiveDate, Utc};
    use serde::{self, Deserialize, Deserializer, Serializer};

    const SERIALIZE_FORMAT: &'static str = "%Y-%m-%d";

    pub fn serialize<S>(date: &Date<Utc>, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        let s = format!("{}", date.format(SERIALIZE_FORMAT));
        serializer.serialize_str(&s)
    }

    pub fn deserialize<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Date<Utc>, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let s = String::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        NaiveDate::parse_from_str(s.as_str(), SERIALIZE_FORMAT)
            .map_err(serde::de::Error::custom)
            .map(|x| {
                let now = Utc::now();
                let date: Date<Utc> = Date::from_utc(x, now.offset().clone());
                date
            })
    }
}
```

then I can do:

```
struct MyStruct {
    #[serde(with = "my_date_format")]
    pub start: Date<Utc>,
}
```

Problem is if I wrap the serialized thing in other types (which are serializable themselves) I get errors:

```
#[serde(with = "my_date_format")]
pub dates: Vec<Date<Utc> // this won't work now since my function doesn't serialize vectors
pub maybe_date: Option<Date<Utc>>> // won't work
pub box_date: Box<Date<Utc>> // won't work...
```

How can I gain the implementations provided while using my own serializer?

https://docs.serde.rs/serde/ser/index.html#implementations-of-serialize-provided-by-serde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of relying on wrapper types it is possible to achieve the same results with the [`serde_as`](https://docs.rs/serde_with/1.6.4/serde_with/guide/serde_as/index.html) macro from the `serde_with` crate.
It works like the serde with attribute but also supports wrapper and collections types.

Since you already have a module to use with serde's with, the hard part is already done.
You can find the details in the [crate documentation](https://docs.rs/serde_with/1.6.4/serde_with/guide/serde_as/index.html#using-serde_as-on-types-without-serializeas-and-serialize-implementations).
You only need to add a local type and two boilerplate implementations for the traits `SerializeAs` and `DeserializeAs` to use your custom transformations.

```rust
use chrono::{Date, NaiveDate, Utc};

struct MyDateFormat;

impl serde_with::SerializeAs<Date<Utc>> for MyDateFormat {
    fn serialize_as<S>(value: &Date<Utc>, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: serde::Serializer,
    {  
        my_date_format::serialize(value, serializer)
    }
}

impl<'de> serde_with::DeserializeAs<'de, Date<Utc>> for MyDateFormat {
    fn deserialize_as<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Date<Utc>, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    {  
        my_date_format::deserialize(deserializer)
    }
}

#[serde_with::serde_as]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    #[serde_as(as = "MyDateFormat")]
    date: Date<Utc>,
    #[serde_as(as = "Vec<MyDateFormat>")]
    dates: Vec<Date<Utc>>,
    #[serde_as(as = "Option<MyDateFormat>")]
    opt_date: Option<Date<Utc>>,
    #[serde_as(as = "Box<MyDateFormat>")]
    boxed_date: Box<Date<Utc>>,
}

fn main() {
    let s = MyStruct {
        date: Utc::now().date().into(),
        dates: std::iter::repeat(Utc::now().date().into()).take(4).collect(),
        opt_date: Some(Utc::now().date().into()),
        boxed_date: Box::new(Utc::now().date().into()),
    };

    let json = serde_json::to_string_pretty(&s).unwrap();
    println!("{}", json);
}

// This module is taken uunmodified from the question
pub mod my_date_format {
    use chrono::{Date, NaiveDate, Utc};
    use serde::{self, Deserialize, Deserializer, Serializer};

    const SERIALIZE_FORMAT: &'static str = "%Y-%m-%d";

    pub fn serialize<S>(date: &Date<Utc>, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        let s = format!("{}", date.format(SERIALIZE_FORMAT));
        serializer.serialize_str(&s)
    }

    pub fn deserialize<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Date<Utc>, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let s = String::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        NaiveDate::parse_from_str(s.as_str(), SERIALIZE_FORMAT)
            .map_err(serde::de::Error::custom)
            .map(|x| {
                let now = Utc::now();
                let date: Date<Utc> = Date::from_utc(x, now.offset().clone());
                date
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The most straight forward way, is to do as the [question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65279642/how-can-i-implement-serde-for-a-type-that-i-dont-own-and-have-it-support-compou) to talks about, i.e. create a new type, wrap `Date<Utc>`, and implement [`Serialize`](https://docs.rs/serde/*/serde/trait.Serialize.html) and [`Deserialize`](https://docs.rs/serde/*/serde/trait.Deserialize.html) for that type.

```rust
#[derive(PartialOrd, Ord, PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Debug)]
struct FormattedDate(Date<Utc>);

impl Serialize for FormattedDate {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        // If you implement `Deref`, then you don't need to add `.0`
        let s = format!("{}", self.0.format(SERIALIZE_FORMAT));
        serializer.serialize_str(&s)
    }
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for FormattedDate {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let s = String::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        NaiveDate::parse_from_str(s.as_str(), SERIALIZE_FORMAT)
            .map_err(serde::de::Error::custom)
            .map(|x| {
                let now = Utc::now();
                let date: Date<Utc> = Date::from_utc(x, now.offset().clone());
                Self(date)
                // or
                // date.into()
            })
    }
}
```

To make life easier, you can implement [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) and [`DerefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html) and then using `FormattedDate` transparently acts as if you're using `Date<Utc>` directly.

```rust
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};

impl Deref for FormattedDate {
    type Target = Date<Utc>;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl DerefMut for FormattedDate {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &mut self.0
    }
}
```

Similarly you can implement [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) and [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html), such that you can easily convert between `FormattedDate` and `Date<Utc>`.

```rust
impl From<Date<Utc>> for FormattedDate {
    fn from(date: Date<Utc>) -> Self {
        Self(date)
    }
}

impl Into<Date<Utc>> for FormattedDate {
    fn into(self) -> Date<Utc> {
        self.0
    }
}
```

Now all the examples you gave works with ease of use:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    date: FormattedDate,
    dates: Vec<FormattedDate>,
    opt_date: Option<FormattedDate>,
    boxed_date: Box<FormattedDate>,
}

fn main() {
    let s = MyStruct {
        date: Utc::now().date().into(),
        dates: std::iter::repeat(Utc::now().date().into()).take(4).collect(),
        opt_date: Some(Utc::now().date().into()),
        boxed_date: Box::new(Utc::now().date().into()),
    };

    let json = serde_json::to_string_pretty(&s).unwrap();
    println!("{}", json);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
{
  "date": "2020-12-13",       
  "dates": [
    "2020-12-13",
    "2020-12-13",
    "2020-12-13",
    "2020-12-13"
  ],
  "opt_date": "2020-12-13",   
  "boxed_date": "2020-12-13"  
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if you want to keep the `MyStruct` containing "real" Date objects you can create a `MyStructRepresentation` struct with the `FormattedDate`s in it and tell serde to serialize and deserialize through the `MyStructRepresentation`.