# How to tell rust to do all float comparisons using a given lib by default?

Tags: rust, operator-overloading, comparison-operators, floating-point-comparison

I would like to have all float comparisons done with `float_cmp::approx_eq` (for example), but keep using the equality comparison operator `==` for it. How do I achieve this?

```
impl PartialEq for f32 {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        approx_eq!(f32, *self, *other)
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::cmp::PartialEq` for type `f32`
error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible:

- This trait implementation is in direct conflict with an existing implementation. There is no trait overriding mechanism. In the future you may be able to *specialize* a generic trait implementation, but this wouldn't be covered by that anyway.
- Rust has ["orphan rules"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/implementations.html#orphan-rules) that govern what trait implementations you are allowed to define. In short, some part of the trait or type must be defined by the current crate. Neither `PartialEq` and `f32` are defined by you, so you cannot create this implementation.
- The [`approx_eq!`](https://docs.rs/float-cmp/latest/float_cmp/macro.approx_eq.html) macro from `float_cmp` expands to code that uses `==` internally, so such implementation if it were allowed would cause infinite recursion.

I don't think there is a way to accomplish this and I'm not sure I'd suggest using it even if there were. This would affect *all* cases where float comparison is done, even deep in your dependencies that could end up causing problems. And this leaves little option to do non-approximate equality even if you explicitly wanted to.

You should handle cases where you only want to consider approximate equality explicitly.

Comment: A newtype wrapper.

Comment: That is certainly worth mentioning, see [How to implement a trait I don't own for a type I don't own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413201/how-do-i-implement-a-trait-i-dont-own-for-a-type-i-dont-own)