# How to implement Default but only for tests?

Tags: rust, traits

I want to provide default values for structs to be used only within tests (and not accidentally in production). I thought that I could make the defaults opt-in by defining my own trait `TestDefault` and implement `Default` for any type that implements it. Then, one could access all the features of the standard `Default` trait using something like this

```rust
use TestDefault; // TestStruct (defined in my crate) implements TestDefault, thus also Default

let test_struct = TestStruct::default();
```

To clarify, I want to implement a foreign trait on local type, which should be allowed, but with an artificial layer of indirection to make it opt-in.

I've tried

```rust
pub trait TestDefault {
    fn test_default() -> Self;
}

impl Default for TestDefault {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::test_default()
    }
}
```

where the compiler complains that `error[E0782]: trait objects must include the 'dyn' keyword`, inserting it instead causes it to fail because `error[E0038]: the trait 'TestDefault' cannot be made into an object`.

Then I tried

```rust
impl<T> Default for T
where
    T: TestDefault,
{
    fn default() -> T {
        T::test_default()
    }
}
```

and got

```
error[E0210]: type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g., `MyStruct<T>`)
   --> src/lib.rs:158:14
    |
158 |         impl<T> Default for T
    |              ^ type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type
    |
    = note: implementing a foreign trait is only possible if at least one of the types for which it is implemented is local
    = note: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter
```

which probably hints at the actual error, but I don't entirely understand it. Is there any way to do this? Or get opt-in default some other way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I implement a trait I don't own for a type I don't own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413201/how-do-i-implement-a-trait-i-dont-own-for-a-type-i-dont-own)

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thanks, but I don't think so. `TestStruct` would be defined in my crate. So I'd still be implementing a foreign trait on a local type which should be allowed, but with an artificial layer of indirection.

Comment: Then why not implement `Default` directly? Anyway, if you're using generics, you're implementing it for any type, not just those defined in your crate.

Comment: The main point was that you only should have access to the default implementations  when manually writing `use TestDefault`, since it would only be a convenience feature for tests and not a practical default.

I took inspiration from how [extension traits](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0445-extension-trait-conventions.html#:~:text=Extension%20traits%20are%20a%20programming,need%20for%20a%20clear%20convention.) work, where you have to `use` them to get access to the associated methods.

It wouldn't be generic though since I have to manually implement `TestDefault` for each of my structs.

Comment: Even if what you want was allowed, this would not be the case - the `Default` implementation will always be available as long as `Default` itself is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `#[cfg(test)]` annotation to only enable the `Default` implementation when testing:

```
struct MyStruct {
    data: u32,
}

#[cfg(test)]
impl Default for MyStruct {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self { data: 42 }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = MyStruct::default(); // FAILS
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        let s = MyStruct::default(); // WORKS
        assert_eq!(s.data, 42);
    }
}
```

```
> cargo test
running 1 test
test tests::it_works ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```

```
> cargo run
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `default` found for struct `MyStruct` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:13:23
   |
1  | struct MyStruct {
   | --------------- function or associated item `default` not found for this
...
13 |     let s = MyStruct::default(); // FAILS
   |                       ^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `MyStruct`
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `default`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `Default`
```

Comment: I had no idea you could use `#[cfg(test)]` on `impl` blocks! That's actually a really good solution to my specific problem, thanks!

Comment: That's what it does, it enables/disables the compilation of code depending on whether it's a test run :)