# How to implement Mul trait for Rgb<u8> and u8?

Tags: rust

In my process of learning Rust I have come across a problem that I don't know how to solve elegantly. I want to do operations on Image::Rgb data, but I get the error that they are not implemented. For example:

```
let rgb = Rgb([40u8, 40, 40]);
let val: u8 = 60;
val*rgb;
```

Results in `the trait Mul<Rgb<u8>> is not implemented for u8`. Of course I can do:

```
rgb.map(|x| x * val);
```

But that results in a mess if there are more operations/several rgb colors. Is there any workaround here? How can I implement that `Mul` trait?

Edit for reference: I have three points (v1, v2, v3) and a color per point. I want to interpolate the color in between the points, just like [here](https://codeplea.com/triangular-interpolation) (the color_p formula). Then not only do I have to do three multiplications but also summing and division. I think `map` too complicated in that case.

Comment: Import the trait and implement the required method, just like any other trait :) https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Mul.html

Comment: @isaactfa [I don't think it will be possible here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25415289/11527076). `Rgb` is from the `image` crate and `Mul` is from `std`.

Comment: Can you give an example of why the `map` approach is undesired? That's the correct way to do this operation.

Comment: @cdhowie I have three points (v1, v2, v3) and a color per point. I want to interpolate the color in between the points, just like here: https://codeplea.com/triangular-interpolation (the color_p formula). Then not only do I have to do three multiplications but also summing and division. Isn't `map` very difficult in that case?

Comment: Destructure the rgb struct `let [r, g, b] = rgb.0` and work on your color values as you would in other languages

Comment: @javirk There's multiple ways that can be addressed. However, `map` is the _exact_ answer to the question you have actually posed ("how to multiply Rgb<u8> and u8"). If you want a different answer then you probably need to ask a different question.

Comment: @cdhowie You are totally right, my mistake. I changed the title to better suit my question.
MeetTitan: If that's the only option, I will do it that way, thanks!

Comment: @prog-fh Oh that's my bad, I didn't realize `Rgb` was from a crate.