# How do I extract hex values as strings?

Tags: rust, hex

I am trying to extract a hash value from a function output:

```rust
let receipt = do_something();
println!("{receipt:?}");
let receipt_txn_hash = receipt.transaction_hash;
println!("receipt_txn_hash: {}", receipt_txn_hash);

let tx = provider.get_transaction(receipt_txn_hash).await?;
println!("tx: {}\n", serde_json::to_string(&tx)?);

let tx_hash = if let Some(txn) = tx {
    txn.hash.to_string()
} else {
    "hash_not_found".to_owned() //H256([0; 32])
};
println!("tx.hash: {}\n", &tx_hash);
```

And it prints out in the terminal:

```
TransactionReceipt { transaction_hash: 0xd6a0e48e6a0f80ae4467193f40721da1ad53ec854a738ea57d7201619e60f3b7, ... }
receipt_txn_hash: 0xd6a0…f3b7

tx: {"hash":"0xd6a0e48e6a0f80ae4467193f40721da1ad53ec854a738ea57d7201619e60f3b7",...}
tx.hash: 0xd6a0…f3b7
```

Somehow Rust-Analyzer identifies this `receipt` has `{unknown}` type, but `tx` has `Option<Transaction>` type.

But still, both the `receipt.transaction_hash`, `tx.hash` have been truncated... **why*?

How can I get the original complete hash value and return it as a String?

Here are the dependencies:

```ini
ethers = { version = "1.0.2", features = ["legacy", "rustls"] }
ethers-solc = { version = "1.0.2", features = ["full"] }
ethers-providers = "1.0.2"
eyre = "0.6.8"
hex = "0.4.3"
reqwest = { version = "0.11.14", default-features = false }
serde_json = "1.0.93"
```

[Update]
Thanks to the answer below, both `receipt_txn_hash` and `tx_hash` are of the type `H256`.

The Display trait of H256 type is defined here:
https://github.com/paritytech/parity-common/blob/223af1dc6c176e35698aed9285f44e428da0050e/fixed-hash/src/hash.rs#L217

```rust
        impl $crate::core_::fmt::Display for $name {
            fn fmt(&self, f: &mut $crate::core_::fmt::Formatter) -> $crate::core_::fmt::Result {
                $crate::core_::write!(f, "0x")?;
                for i in &self.0[0..2] {
                    $crate::core_::write!(f, "{:02x}", i)?;
                }
                $crate::core_::write!(f, "…")?;
                for i in &self.0[$n_bytes - 2..$n_bytes] {
                    $crate::core_::write!(f, "{:02x}", i)?;
                }
                Ok(())
            }
        }
```

From the Display trait definition above, we know Display trait is causing the truncation.

So we need to modify the Display trait(defined in our dependencies).

But we cannot modify or override the foreign trait definition due to: `only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for types defined outside of the crate. Define and implement a trait or new type instead`

So we have to make our local type to modify the foreign trait!

Hence, this question is basically asking how to implement a local type(NewH256), on a foreign trait(fmt::Display)?

Comment: What are the packages involved? What are the types involved?

Comment: @Masklinn Please have a look at my dependencies above

Comment: Please provide a [MRE], with a `main` and `use` statements that can simply be copied, pasted and reproduces the exact output you claim it does.

Comment: The `do_something` function does not exist; the `provider` variable also does not exist. Both are crucial to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by a quick search I'm guessing the type is a `H256` from [here](https://docs.rs/web3/latest/web3/types/struct.TransactionReceipt.html#structfield.transaction_hash).
This has a `Display` implementation [here](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-common/blob/223af1dc6c176e35698aed9285f44e428da0050e/fixed-hash/src/hash.rs#L217) which gives you your ellipses.

If you want to show the full hex, you might be best just printing the debug output:

```rust
println!("receipt_txn_hash: {:?}", receipt_txn_hash);
```

If that doesn't work, you can just copy the `Display` impl and format it however you want.

Comment: Solved by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413201/how-do-i-implement-a-trait-i-dont-own-for-a-type-i-dont-own