# Error in passing this struct implementation to a thread in rust

Tags: multithreading, rust

I've been working in understanding and using structs and impl as I mostly stick to mod and fn at most. I want to implement this window struct which impl's would manage every function a window may need. In making this I've realized I may need to launch the updating event in a separate thread, wherein I've ran into a problem. I think it may have to do with the crate I'm using in itself, although I'd love to know what's the proper way to do this (if it even is one and this isn't very bad code practice or idea).

This is my code:

```
#![allow(unused_imports)]
#![allow(dead_code)]
use minifb::*;
use std::io;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

struct WindowGui {
    name: String,
    height: usize, //i32
    width: usize,  //i32
    buffer: Vec<u32>,
}

impl WindowGui {
    fn window(&self) -> Window {
        let window = Window::new(
            &self.name,
            self.width,
            self.height,
            WindowOptions {
                resize: true,
                ..WindowOptions::default()
            }, //WindowOptions::default(),
        )
        .expect("Error Creating windows");
        return window;
    }
    fn update(&self, mut window: Window) {
        while window.is_open() && !window.is_key_down(Key::Escape) {
            window
                .update_with_buffer(&self.buffer, self.width, self.height)
                .expect("Couldn't update window with current pixel buffer");
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let name = String::from("yoo");
    let buffer: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    let win = WindowGui {
        name,
        height: 1,
        width: 2,
        buffer,
    };
    let mut window_instance = win.window();
    let screen = thread::spawn(move || {
            win.update(window_instance);
    });
    let mut bla = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut bla).expect("no");
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Which, as I exeute it, yields 8 errors which I'm unsure how to deal with as I'm not very confident with how to deal with threads and possesion/borrowing etc (also static) in this context:

```
error[E0277]: `*mut winapi::shared::windef::HBRUSH__` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src\main.rs:50:32
    |
50  |       let screen = thread::spawn(move || {
    |                    ------------- ^------
    |                    |             |
    |  __________________|_____________within this `[closure@src\main.rs:50:32: 50:39]`
    | |                  |
    | |                  required by a bound introduced by this call
51  | |             win.update(window_instance);
52  | |     });
    | |_____^ `*mut winapi::shared::windef::HBRUSH__` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: within `[closure@src\main.rs:50:32: 50:39]`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `*mut winapi::shared::windef::HBRUSH__`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Window`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Window`
note: required because it's used within this closure
   --> src\main.rs:50:32
    |
50  |     let screen = thread::spawn(move || {
    |                                ^^^^^^^
note: required by a bound in `spawn`
   --> C:\Users\hecto\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib/rustlib/src/rust\library\std\src\thread\mod.rs:714:8
    |
714 |     F: Send + 'static,
    |        ^^^^ required by this bound in `spawn`

error[E0277]: `*mut winapi::shared::windef::HACCEL__` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src\main.rs:50:32
    |
50  |       let screen = thread::spawn(move || {
    |                    ------------- ^------
    |                    |             |
    |  __________________|_____________within this `[closure@src\main.rs:50:32: 50:39]`
    | |                  |
    | |                  required by a bound introduced by this call
51  | |             win.update(window_instance);
52  | |     });
    | |_____^ `*mut winapi::shared::windef::HACCEL__` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: within `[closure@src\main.rs:50:32: 50:39]`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `*mut winapi::shared::windef::HACCEL__`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Window`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Window`
note: required because it's used within this closure
   --> src\main.rs:50:32
    |
50  |     let screen = thread::spawn(move || {
    |                                ^^^^^^^
note: required by a bound in `spawn`
   --> C:\Users\hecto\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib/rustlib/src/rust\library\std\src\thread\mod.rs:714:8
    |
714 |     F: Send + 'static,
    |        ^^^^ required by this bound in `spawn`

error[E0277]: `*mut winapi::shared::windef::HDC__` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src\main.rs:50:32
    |
50  |       let screen = thread::spawn(move || {
    |                    ------------- ^------
    |                    |             |
    |  __________________|_____________within this `[closure@src\main.rs:50:32: 50:39]`
    | |                  |
    | |                  required by a bound introduced by this call
51  | |             win.update(window_instance);
52  | |     });
    | |_____^ `*mut winapi::shared::windef::HDC__` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: within `[closure@src\main.rs:50:32: 50:39]`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `*mut winapi::shared::windef::HDC__`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Option<*mut HDC__>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Window`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Window`
note: required because it's used within this closure
   --> src\main.rs:50:32
    |
50  |     let screen = thread::spawn(move || {
    |                                ^^^^^^^
note: required by a bound in `spawn`
   --> C:\Users\hecto\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib/rustlib/src/rust\library\std\src\thread\mod.rs:714:8
    |
714 |     F: Send + 'static,
    |        ^^^^ required by this bound in `spawn`

error[E0277]: `*mut winapi::shared::windef::HWND__` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src\main.rs:50:32
    |
50  |       let screen = thread::spawn(move || {
    |                    ------------- ^------
    |                    |             |
    |  __________________|_____________within this `[closure@src\main.rs:50:32: 50:39]`
    | |                  |
    | |                  required by a bound introduced by this call
51  | |             win.update(window_instance);
52  | |     });
    | |_____^ `*mut winapi::shared::windef::HWND__` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: within `[closure@src\main.rs:50:32: 50:39]`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `*mut winapi::shared::windef::HWND__`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Option<*mut HWND__>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Window`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Window`
note: required because it's used within this closure
   --> src\main.rs:50:32
    |
50  |     let screen = thread::spawn(move || {
    |                                ^^^^^^^
note: required by a bound in `spawn`
   --> C:\Users\hecto\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib/rustlib/src/rust\library\std\src\thread\mod.rs:714:8
    |
714 |     F: Send + 'static,
    |        ^^^^ required by this bound in `spawn`

error[E0277]: `*mut winapi::shared::windef::HICON__` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src\main.rs:50:32
    |
50  |       let screen = thread::spawn(move || {
    |                    ------------- ^------
    |                    |             |
    |  __________________|_____________within this `[closure@src\main.rs:50:32: 50:39]`
    | |                  |
    | |                  required by a bound introduced by this call
51  | |             win.update(window_instance);
52  | |     });
    | |_____^ `*mut winapi::shared::windef::HICON__` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: within `[closure@src\main.rs:50:32: 50:39]`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `*mut winapi::shared::windef::HICON__`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `[*mut HICON__; 8]`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Window`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Window`
note: required because it's used within this closure
   --> src\main.rs:50:32
    |
50  |     let screen = thread::spawn(move || {
    |                                ^^^^^^^
note: required by a bound in `spawn`
   --> C:\Users\hecto\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib/rustlib/src/rust\library\std\src\thread\mod.rs:714:8
    |
714 |     F: Send + 'static,
    |        ^^^^ required by this bound in `spawn`

error[E0277]: `*const u32` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src\main.rs:50:32
    |
50  |       let screen = thread::spawn(move || {
    |                    ------------- ^------
    |                    |             |
    |  __________________|_____________within this `[closure@src\main.rs:50:32: 50:39]`
    | |                  |
    | |                  required by a bound introduced by this call
51  | |             win.update(window_instance);
52  | |     });
    | |_____^ `*const u32` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: within `[closure@src\main.rs:50:32: 50:39]`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `*const u32`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `DrawParameters`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Window`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Window`
note: required because it's used within this closure
   --> src\main.rs:50:32
    |
50  |     let screen = thread::spawn(move || {
    |                                ^^^^^^^
note: required by a bound in `spawn`
   --> C:\Users\hecto\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib/rustlib/src/rust\library\std\src\thread\mod.rs:714:8
    |
714 |     F: Send + 'static,
    |        ^^^^ required by this bound in `spawn`

error[E0277]: `*mut winapi::shared::windef::HMENU__` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src\main.rs:50:32
    |
50  |       let screen = thread::spawn(move || {
    |  __________________-------------_^
    | |                  |
    | |                  required by a bound introduced by this call
51  | |             win.update(window_instance);
52  | |     });
    | |_____^ `*mut winapi::shared::windef::HMENU__` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: within `minifb::os::windows::Menu`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `*mut winapi::shared::windef::HMENU__`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Menu`
    = note: required for `Unique<minifb::os::windows::Menu>` to implement `Send`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `RawVec<Menu>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Vec<Menu>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Window`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Window`
note: required because it's used within this closure
   --> src\main.rs:50:32
    |
50  |     let screen = thread::spawn(move || {
    |                                ^^^^^^^
note: required by a bound in `spawn`
   --> C:\Users\hecto\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib/rustlib/src/rust\library\std\src\thread\mod.rs:714:8
    |
714 |     F: Send + 'static,
    |        ^^^^ required by this bound in `spawn`

error[E0277]: `(dyn InputCallback + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src\main.rs:50:32
    |
50  |       let screen = thread::spawn(move || {
    |  __________________-------------_^
    | |                  |
    | |                  required by a bound introduced by this call
51  | |             win.update(window_instance);
52  | |     });
    | |_____^ `(dyn InputCallback + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: the trait `Send` is not implemented for `(dyn InputCallback + 'static)`
    = note: required for `Unique<(dyn InputCallback + 'static)>` to implement `Send`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Box<dyn InputCallback>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Option<Box<dyn InputCallback>>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `KeyHandler`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Window`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Window`
note: required because it's used within this closure
   --> src\main.rs:50:32
    |
50  |     let screen = thread::spawn(move || {
    |                                ^^^^^^^
note: required by a bound in `spawn`
   --> C:\Users\hecto\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib/rustlib/src/rust\library\std\src\thread\mod.rs:714:8
    |
714 |     F: Send + 'static,
    |        ^^^^ required by this bound in `spawn`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `gui_program` due to 8 previous errors
```

Edit 1: I've come to realize it probably is an implementation issue of the crate, still, is there a way I could make this work?

Edit 2: Neither the Send or Copy traits are implemented for minifb::Window, can I intercede in that and or make it work without these?

Comment: It's not clear why you want to create the window in a different thread than you're using it, jjust move the `let window_instance = ...` line inside the thread that's using it‽

Comment: @cafce25 it's to have the window drawing/updating in a different thread than say, processing or buffer writting, although by now I've figured that I might as well keep the window in the main thread and move the rest to separate threads, still, my question stands, as I'd like to know if I can "append" or circunvalate this problem somehow, if I needed to, I want to understand the in and outs of that. Also, could I, for example, implement a fn Copy of an object from a crate for example? that's something I'd be interested to see if it could help for example in this problem.

Comment: You [can't in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413201/how-do-i-implement-a-trait-i-dont-own-for-a-type-i-dont-own), and `Copy` is even more special as even the workarounds in that Q/A don't work for it. Also `Copy` doesn't help you as that's not the issue here. Afaik there isn't a sound way to implement `Send` either.

Comment: Usually GUIs can only be manipulated from the main thread.