# Can I implement a generic From<> trait for a generic type for any other implementation than from itself?

Tags: templates, rust, type-conversion

I made a generic Vector struct, used with different T types :

```rs
struct Vector<T> {
    data: [T; 3],
}
```

I already implemented some generic traits for mathematical operands (`Eq`, `Index`, `std::ops::Add`...) and it works fine.

But now, I am struggling with implementing a `From` trait so I can easily convert, for instance, a Vector into a Vector.

```rs
impl<T, U> From<Vector<U>> for Vector<T> {
    fn from(item: Vector<U>) -> Self {
        // [...]
    }
}
```

Regardless of this `from` function's implementation, I get the following error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `From<Vector<_>>` for type `Vector<_>`
 --> <source>:5:1
  |
5 | impl<T, U> From<Vector<U>> for Vector<T> {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
          - impl<T> From<T> for T;
```

If I understand correctly, it is because by default, for any type, `From<Vector<T>> for Vector<T>` is already declared. And my implementation conflicts with it if `T` and `U` are identical types.

So is there a way to use my implementation for any **different** types `T` and `U`, but not use it for **identical** types `T` and `U` ?

Comment: You [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25413201/5397009) since you own neither `From`, nor `Vector` nor all possible `T` and `U`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write this implementation.

Even if you were the owner of `From` you could not write this bound, as it conflicts with `impl<T> From<T> for T` where `T == U`. In fact, some people want the standard library to write this impl for collections (for example, `Option<T>`), and despite the standard library being the owner of `From` it cannot provide this impl.

You can provide a method to do that, instead of a trait implementation.